# python - exe using pyinstaller problems

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyinstaller, exe

Source code:

**File: epalxeis-radio.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'epalxeis-radio.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(452, 153)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/epalxeis-radio/epalxeis.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(170, 255, 127);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.play_or_pause = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.play_or_pause.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
        self.play_or_pause.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/pause-song.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.play_or_pause.setIcon(icon1)
        self.play_or_pause.setObjectName("play_or_pause")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.play_or_pause, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.volume_slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.volume_slider.setMaximum(200)
        self.volume_slider.setProperty("value", 100)
        self.volume_slider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volume_slider.setObjectName("volume_slider")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.volume_slider, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.volume_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.volume_label.setObjectName("volume_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.volume_label, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line, 1, 0, 1, 5)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.record_start_or_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.record_start_or_stop.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
        self.record_start_or_stop.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/start-recording.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.record_start_or_stop.setIcon(icon2)
        self.record_start_or_stop.setObjectName("record_start_or_stop")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.record_start_or_stop, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_5, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.record_time = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.record_time.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.record_time.setObjectName("record_time")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.record_time, 2, 3, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Epalxeis record player"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Player:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Volume:"))
        self.volume_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "100/200"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Record:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Record time:"))
        self.record_time.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "00:00:00"))
import icons_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**File: epalxeis-main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe, freeze_support
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment,effects,utils,generators
import pyaudio
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL, STDOUT, PIPE
import subprocess
import os
import importlib
import math
import traceback
import sys
import base64
import psutil
import pexpect
import copy
from pprint import pprint, pformat

from sys import platform
import getpass

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import which

from io import BytesIO

epalxeis_ui_compiled = importlib.import_module("epalxeis-radio")


class Record_Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = epalxeis_ui_compiled.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        #prevent user resize
        self.MainWindow.setFixedSize(452, 153)
        self.MainWindow.show()

        #create process
        self.mother_pipe, self.child_pipe = Pipe()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.emitter = Emitter(self.mother_pipe)
        self.emitter.record_duration_milliseconds.connect(lambda duration:self.record_duration_milliseconds(duration))
        self.emitter.start()
        self.child_process = Child_Proc(self.child_pipe, self.queue)
        self.child_process.start()

        #on sound volume changed
        self.ui.volume_slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda slider_value:self.volume_changed(slider_value))

        #on sound volume apply new value
        self.ui.volume_slider.sliderReleased.connect(lambda:self.volume_released())

        #on sound volume pressed
        self.ui.volume_slider.actionTriggered.connect(lambda action:self.volume_action_triggered(action))

        self.play_status = "playing"
        self.record_status = "stopped"
        self.record_folder = None
        
        #on play or pause clicked
        self.ui.play_or_pause.clicked.connect(lambda state:self.play_or_pause_clicked(state))
        
        #on record start or stop
        self.ui.record_start_or_stop.clicked.connect(lambda state:self.record_start_or_stop_clicked(state))

        self.MainWindow.closeEvent = lambda event:self.closeEvent(event)
        self.app.setStyle('Fusion')
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    def record_duration_milliseconds(self,duration):
        duration_human = self.convert_duration_from_milliseconds_to_human(duration)
        self.ui.record_time.setText(duration_human)

    def play_or_pause_clicked(self,state):
        if self.play_status == "stopped":
            self.play_status = "playing"
            icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/pause-song.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.play_or_pause.setIcon(icon4)
            self.queue.put({"type":"play"})
        elif self.play_status == "paused":
            self.play_status = "playing"
            icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/pause-song.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.play_or_pause.setIcon(icon4)
            self.queue.put({"type":"play"})
        elif self.play_status == "playing":
            self.play_status = "paused"
            icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/play-song.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.play_or_pause.setIcon(icon4)
            self.queue.put({"type":"pause"})

    def record_start_or_stop_clicked(self,state):
        if self.record_status == "stopped":
            if self.record_folder == None:            
                sys_username = getpass.getuser()
                try:
                    dialog_dir = os.path.abspath("C:/Users/"+sys_username+"/")
                except:
                    dialog_dir = QtCore.QDir.currentPath()
                self.record_folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.MainWindow, 'Επιλογή φακέλου αποθήκευσης',dialog_dir)
                if os.path.exists(self.record_folder)==False:
                    self.record_folder = None
            
            if self.record_folder == None:
                return None
        
            self.record_status = "record"
            icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/record-stop.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.record_start_or_stop.setIcon(icon4)
            self.queue.put({"type":"record","folder":self.record_folder})
        elif self.record_status == "record":
            self.record_status = "stopped"
            self.ui.record_time.setText("00:00:00")
            icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/start-recording.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.ui.record_start_or_stop.setIcon(icon4)
            self.queue.put({"type":"stop-record"})
            self.record_folder = None

    def volume_changed(self,slider_value):
        self.ui.volume_label.setText(str(slider_value)+"/200")
        
    def volume_released(self):
        slider_value = self.ui.volume_slider.value()
        self.queue.put({"type":"volume","value_base_100":slider_value})
    

    def volume_action_triggered(self,action):
        if action == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderSingleStepAdd or action == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderSingleStepSub or action == QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderPageStepAdd or action== QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider.SliderPageStepSub:
            self.timer_2 = QtCore.QTimer()  # set up your QTimer
            self.timer_2.timeout.connect(lambda:self.volume_released())  # connect it to your update function
            self.timer_2.setSingleShot(True)
            self.timer_2.start(500)  # set it to timeout in 200 ms            

    def convert_duration_from_milliseconds_to_human(self,duration_milliseconds):
        total_seconds = int(duration_milliseconds/1000)
        #1. find how much hours total_seconds are
        hours = int(total_seconds/(60*60))
        #2. calculate seconds remaining
        seconds_remaining = total_seconds-(hours*60*60)
        #3. find how much minutes seconds_remaining are
        minutes = int(seconds_remaining/60)
        #4. recalculate seconds remaining
        seconds = seconds_remaining-(minutes*60)
        
        #add leading zero
        if(seconds<10):
            seconds = "0"+str(seconds)
        if(minutes<10):
            minutes = "0"+str(minutes)
        if(hours<10):
            hours = "0"+str(hours)
        
        return str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)+":"+str(seconds)

        
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.queue.put({"type":"stop"})
        time.sleep(1)
        self.child_process.terminate()
        self.emitter.quit()
        event.accept()
                    
class Emitter(QThread):
    error_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    record_duration_milliseconds = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def __init__(self, from_process: Pipe):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_from_process = from_process
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.data_from_process.recv()
            if data["type"] == "error":
                self.error_signal.emit(data["error_message"])
            elif data["type"] == "record-duration":
                self.record_duration_milliseconds.emit(data["duration"])

class Child_Proc(Process):

    def __init__(self, to_emitter, from_mother):    
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = False
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter
        self.data_from_mother = from_mother
        self.retransmition_url = "http://shaincast.caster.fm:40636/listen.mp3?authn76260dc1cdf44a9132c0b63f85d9c67a"
        self.volume = 100
        self.ffmpeg_path = os.path.abspath("extra/ffmpeg.exe")
        self.record_folder = None
        self.record_duration_milliseconds = 0
        if os.path.exists("epalxeis-radio.mp3"):
            os.remove("epalxeis-radio.mp3")

    def run(self):
            self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

            self.bit_rate = 128*1024 #128 kb/sec
            self.packet_time = 125
            self.packet_size = 4096
            self.new_sample_rate = 44800


            self.format = pyaudio.paInt16
            self.channels = 2

            self.stream = None
            self.play_status = "stopped"
            
            self.record_status = "stopped"
            
            sine_segment = generators.Sine(1000).to_audio_segment()
            sine_segment = sine_segment.set_frame_rate(self.new_sample_rate)
            sine_segment = sine_segment[(1000-int(self.packet_time))/2:self.packet_time+(1000-int(self.packet_time))/2]
            self.silent_segment = sine_segment-200
            
            
            self.play_status_changed("stopped")
            if self.play_status=="stopped":                    
                self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=self.channels,rate=self.new_sample_rate,output=True,frames_per_buffer=self.packet_size)
                self.stream.start_stream()
                self.chunk_number = 0
                self.current_duration_milliseconds = 0
            else:
                pass
            self.play_status_changed("playing")
            
            while(True):
                if self.play_status == "stopped":
                    data = self.data_from_mother.get()
                else:
                    q_size = self.data_from_mother.qsize()
                    if q_size>0:
                        data = self.data_from_mother.get()
                    else:
                        data = None
                if data is not None:
                    if data["type"] == "play":
                        self.play_status_changed("stopped")
                        if self.play_status=="stopped":                    
                            self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=self.channels,rate=self.new_sample_rate,output=True,frames_per_buffer=self.packet_size)
                            self.stream.start_stream()
                            self.chunk_number = 0
                            self.current_duration_milliseconds = 0
                        else:
                            pass
                        self.play_status_changed("playing")
                    elif data["type"] == "pause":
                        self.play_status_changed("paused")
                    elif data["type"] == "stop":
                        self.play_status_changed("stopped")
                    elif data["type"] == "volume":
                        self.volume = int(data["value_base_100"])
                    elif data["type"] == "record":
                        self.record_folder = data["folder"]
                        now = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
                        self.record_path = os.path.join(self.record_folder,"epalxeis-radio record "+now+".mp3")
                        self.record_file = open(self.record_path, 'wb')
                        self.record_status = "record"
                    elif data["type"] == "stop-record":
                        self.record_status = "stopped"
                        self.record_duration_milliseconds = 0
                        self.record_file.close()
                        self.to_emitter.send({"type":"record-duration","duration":self.record_duration_milliseconds})
                if self.play_status=="playing":
                    if len(self.mp3_q)<self.packet_time:
                        chunk = False
                        while not chunk:
                            chunk = self.mp3_stream_file.read(32*self.packet_size)
                            if not chunk:
                                time.sleep(0.1)
                            else:
                                record_chunk = chunk
                        

                        chunk = BytesIO(chunk)
                        success = False
                        while (success == False):
                            try:
                                slice = AudioSegment.from_mp3(chunk)        
                                self.record_duration_milliseconds += len(slice)
                                success = True
                            except:
                                success = False
                        slice = slice.set_frame_rate(self.new_sample_rate)
                        mp3_q_len = len(self.mp3_q)
                        self.mp3_q = self.mp3_q + slice
                        slice = self.mp3_q[0:self.packet_time]
                        self.mp3_q = self.mp3_q[self.packet_time:]
                    else:
                        slice = self.mp3_q[0:self.packet_time]
                        self.mp3_q = self.mp3_q[self.packet_time:]                  
                                
                    if(self.volume==0):
                        db_volume = -200
                    else:   
                        db_volume =  20*math.log10(self.volume/100)
                    
                    slice = slice+db_volume
                    
                    self.stream.write(slice.raw_data)

                    
                    self.chunk_number += 1
                    self.current_duration_milliseconds += self.packet_time
                    duration_human = self.convert_duration_from_milliseconds_to_human(self.current_duration_milliseconds)


                    #self.to_emitter.send({"type":"duration_signal","duration_human":duration_human,"duration_milliseconds":self.current_duration_milliseconds})
                    
                    if self.record_status == "record":
                        self.record_file.write(record_chunk)
                        record_chunk = b""
                        self.to_emitter.send({"type":"record-duration","duration":self.record_duration_milliseconds})

    def play_status_changed(self,new_status):
        if new_status == "playing":
            if self.play_status == "stopped":
                self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=self.channels,rate=self.new_sample_rate,output=True,frames_per_buffer=self.packet_size)
                self.stream.start_stream()
                self.play_status = "playing"
                self.chunk_number = 0
                self.current_duration_milliseconds = 0
                                
                try:
                    try:
                        self.p1.communicate(b"q")
                        self.p1.terminate()
                        self.p1.wait()
                    except:
                        pass
                        
                    try:
                        self.mp3_stream_file.close()
                    except:
                        pass
                    
                    if os.path.exists("epalxeis-radio.mp3"):
                        os.remove("epalxeis-radio.mp3")
                except:
                    pass
                
                
                self.p1 = Popen([self.ffmpeg_path,'-y','-loglevel','quiet','-i',self.retransmition_url,'epalxeis-radio.mp3'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1)
                stream_file_exists = False
                while(stream_file_exists==False):
                    if os.path.exists("epalxeis-radio.mp3"):
                        stream_file_exists = True
                        self.mp3_stream_file = None
                    else:
                        time.sleep(1)
                self.mp3_stream_file = open("epalxeis-radio.mp3","rb")
                self.mp3_q = AudioSegment.empty()
            else:
                self.play_status = "playing"
                
                try:
                    try:
                        self.p1.communicate(b"q")
                        self.p1.terminate()
                        self.p1.wait()
                    except:
                        pass
                        
                    try:
                        self.mp3_stream_file.close()
                    except:
                        pass
                    
                    if os.path.exists("epalxeis-radio.mp3"):
                        os.remove("epalxeis-radio.mp3")
                except:
                    pass

                self.p1 = Popen([self.ffmpeg_path,'-y','-loglevel','quiet','-i',self.retransmition_url,'epalxeis-radio.mp3'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1)
                stream_file_exists = False
                while(stream_file_exists==False):
                    if os.path.exists("epalxeis-radio.mp3"):
                        stream_file_exists = True
                    else:
                        time.sleep(1)
                self.mp3_stream_file = open("epalxeis-radio.mp3","rb")
                self.mp3_q = AudioSegment.empty()
        elif new_status == "stopped":
            self.play_status = "stopped"
            self.chunk_number = 0
            self.current_duration_milliseconds = 0
            try:
                self.stream.stop_stream()
                self.stream.close()
            except:
                pass
            
            try:
                try:
                    self.p1.communicate(b"q")
                    self.p1.terminate()
                    self.p1.wait()
                except:
                    pass
                    
                try:
                    self.mp3_stream_file.close()
                except:
                    pass
                
                if os.path.exists("epalxeis-radio.mp3"):
                    os.remove("epalxeis-radio.mp3")
            except:
                pass
        elif new_status == "paused":
            self.play_status = "paused"
            
            try:
                try:
                    self.p1.communicate(b"q")
                    self.p1.terminate()
                    self.p1.wait()
                except:
                    pass
                    
                try:
                    self.mp3_stream_file.close()
                except:
                    pass
                
                if os.path.exists("epalxeis-radio.mp3"):
                    os.remove("epalxeis-radio.mp3")
            except:
                pass
                
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(["attrib","+H","epalxeis-radio.mp3"])
        except:
            pass
            
        if self.record_status == "record":
            self.record_file.close()

    def convert_duration_from_milliseconds_to_human(self,duration_milliseconds):
        total_seconds = int(duration_milliseconds/1000)
        #1. find how much hours total_seconds are
        hours = int(total_seconds/(60*60))
        #2. calculate seconds remaining
        seconds_remaining = total_seconds-(hours*60*60)
        #3. find how much minutes seconds_remaining are
        minutes = int(seconds_remaining/60)
        #4. recalculate seconds remaining
        seconds = seconds_remaining-(minutes*60)
        
        #add leading zero
        if(seconds<10):
            seconds = "0"+str(seconds)
        if(minutes<10):
            minutes = "0"+str(minutes)
        if(hours<10):
            hours = "0"+str(hours)
        
        return str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)+":"+str(seconds)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = Record_Player()
    freeze_support()
```

**pyinstaller command**

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --debug=all --icon "C:/Users/chris/My Projects/epalxeis-radio/epalxeis.ico" --add-data "C:/Users/chris/My Projects/epalxeis-radio/epalxeis-radio.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/chris/My Projects/epalxeis-radio/icons_rc.py;." --hidden-import "inflect" --hidden-import "pydub" --hidden-import "pyaudio" --hidden-import "pydub.utils" --hidden-import "pydub.generators" --hidden-import "multiprocessing" --hidden-import "encodings" --hidden-import "importlib" "C:/Users/chris/My Projects/epalxeis-radio/epalxeis-main.py"
```

Execution console message are too large to post.
There are ModuleNotFound at least one error. (importlib encondings). Also there is this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "epalxeis-main.py", line 479, in <module>
  File "epalxeis-main.py", line 52, in __init__
  File "multiprocessing\context.py", line 61, in Pipe
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocessing.connection'
```

But there is also one more issue: The ui it's open and open again over loop (I used freeze_support) but there is no change.

How can I make the right pyinstaller command?

Comment: why are you using importlib to import a module that is in the same directory and already on the system import path?